# distribute php application in ubuntu software centre

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, software-distribution

I recently noticed that the world needs a ubuntu based POS system for SME(which is not a restaurant). I couldn't find one available. So I decided to write one for myself. I wish to share the software with rest of linux/ubuntu users.

So does anybody know a method where by I can distribute a php application. What confuses me is:

1. End user shouldnt be pestered while installing LAMP [ seems impossible already ]
2. create fogger app using installer so that the application opens in a direct window instead of firefox/other browser
3. rights/ownership decision of php files.

I know its a hard question, but if this can be done, I do have skills and time to create some much needed applications.

Comment: the most common php web application that I install on my ubuntu sytem is PhpMyAdmin using apt-get install phpmyadmin. So maybe you can take a look at how it's done for this software.

Comment: You'll have to look at the DebianPackaging policy and the Ubuntu modifications to the DebianPackagingPolicy. I believe you can find all of those at developer.ubuntu.com